# Does not open the window in SDL2 tutorial due to libEGL: failed to authenticate warning

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, sdl-2

I tried [this](https://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/17/lesson-1-hello-world) SDL tutorial.
I attempted execute following simple code in tutorial.
But it raise a warning when execute it, so it does not open the window.

I considered that this error caused by symlink referring to [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61078/qt-applications-dont-work-due-to-libegl).
But libEGL.so.1 already exists in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
```

---

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include <memory>

int main() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateWindow Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    auto *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED|SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if (ren == nullptr) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        std::cout << "SDL_CreateRenderer Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Ubuntu Linux 18.10 on virtualbox.
Host OS: Windows 10

#### Edit

I have installed virtualbox-guest-additions:

```
modinfo vboxguest
filename:       /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/misc/vboxguest.ko
version:        6.0.4 r128413
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     95F53B9B95BC6E03156A1D8
alias:          pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc*sc*i*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           vboxguest
vermagic:       4.18.0-15-generic SMP mod_unload
```

#### Edit2

xdpyinfo output (This is not all, output is too long, so This is several lines of top of output.

```
name of display:    :0
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    12001000
X.Org version: 1.20.1
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes
motion buffer size:  256
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32
image byte order:    LSBFirst
number of supported pixmap formats:    7
supported pixmap formats:
    depth 1, bits_per_pixel 1, scanline_pad 32
    depth 4, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 8, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 15, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 16, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 24, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
    depth 32, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
keycode range:    minimum 8, maximum 255
focus:  window 0x2e00007, revert to Parent
number of extensions:    27
    BIG-REQUESTS
    Composite
    DAMAGE
    DOUBLE-BUFFER
    DPMS
    DRI2
    GLX
    Generic Event Extension
    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    MIT-SHM
    Present
    RANDR
    RECORD
    RENDER
    SECURITY
    SHAPE
    SYNC
    X-Resource
    XC-MISC
    XFIXES
    XFree86-DGA
    XFree86-VidModeExtension
    XINERAMA
    XInputExtension
    XKEYBOARD
    XTEST
    XVideo
default screen number:    0
number of screens:    1

screen #0:
  dimensions:    952x966 pixels (251x255 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
  root window id:    0x2bd
  depth of root window:    24 planes
  number of colormaps:    minimum 1, maximum 1
  default colormap:    0x20
  default number of colormap cells:    256
  preallocated pixels:    black 0, white 16777215
  options:    backing-store WHEN MAPPED, save-unders NO
  largest cursor:    64x64
  current input event mask:    0xda0003
    KeyPressMask             KeyReleaseMask           StructureNotifyMask      
    SubstructureNotifyMask   SubstructureRedirectMask PropertyChangeMask       
    ColormapChangeMask       
  number of visuals:    270
  default visual id:  0x21
  visual:
    visual id:    0x21
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
```

Xorg log (several line of tail of Xorg log):

```
[    14.691] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse'
[    14.694] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 28 paused 0
[    14.694] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: always reports core events
[    14.694] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    14.694] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    14.696] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    14.696] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device is a pointer
[    14.696] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device removed
[    14.696] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4/event3"
[    14.697] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[    14.697] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    14.697] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    14.697] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    14.698] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    14.699] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    14.699] (II) event3  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device is a pointer
[    14.700] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    14.700] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    14.700] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.545] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "VBX", prod id 0
[    16.545] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: 952x966 Warning: We only handle separate sync.
[    16.545] (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[    16.545] (II) modeset(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[    16.549] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "VBX", prod id 0
[    16.549] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: 952x966 Warning: We only handle separate sync.
[    16.549] (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[    16.549] (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[    17.169] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "VBX", prod id 0
[    17.169] (II) modeset(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: 952x966 Warning: We only handle separate sync.
[    17.169] (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
```

glxgears:
[image: flxgears picture]

Comment: Your virtualbox display driver probably doesn't support DRI. Do you have virtualbox-guest-additions installed?

Comment: I have installed. I added information of virtualbox-guest-additions.

Comment: Did you restart xserver after installing guest additiins? Look at xdpyinfo output and x.org log, see if there are any messages abiut DRI.

Comment: I did reboot ubuntu vm installed it after.

xdpyinfo and Xorg log added

Comment: Looks like there is DRI2 support in the server. Are you running your program as a different user by any chance? Can you start any X/OpenGL program from the same terminal?

Comment: What application using OpenGL?
For example, I can start gedit from my terminal with `gedit` command, but I dont know whether it use OpenGL.

Comment: It probably doesn't. Try program called glxgears.

Comment: glxgears works on my VM.

Comment: Is it using DRI? Try to enable debug and see, or just make sure it's reasonably fast. Otherwise, I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: how do i check whether it use dri?

Comment: I honestly don't know, look at the source, there should be some environment to totn on debugging output or something. If it runs at say 30 fps then probably it's using DRI, if 3 fps then probably not.